# Google TAG Manager server preview only manual data receiving

Tags: google-tag-manager

When I hit my server url `https://gtm.epeey.com` it should show request my server preview server but until I send any manual data including `X-Gtm-Server-Preview HTTP header` request not showing in my gtm server preview. can anyone please help me. It should show the data when any request hit`gtm.epeey.com`. I am using my own server. my nginx configuration

```
 location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
         location /g/ {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
        }


        location /gtm/ {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        }
```

on port 8080 my preview server running and 8081 running on server-side tagging cluster